# In FantasyCraft, how do the martial classes do more damage as they level up?

Tags: fantasycraft

I have been reading through FantasyCraft, and am quite puzzled by how the martial classes (Soldier, Captain, Paladin etc.) do more damage with their attack as they level up. Unlike D20, there aren't any iterative attacks - and looking through the feats, only a few increase the amount of damage dealt (Knife Supremacy and Sword Supremacy, for example).

What am I missing?

Comment: Not having read FC, but being familiar with many fantasy games, it is possible that damage and monster HP simply don't follow the arms race that they do in the d20 System editions of D&D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been playing a Captain 1/Soldier 6 for about 6 months.  I can't really comment on d20 as I'm still a (returned) newbie to the rpg world, but I take it from @SevenSidedDie's comment that the number of attacks offered to martial classes generally increases as their level increases.

In FantasyCraft, it comes down to the composition of feats, proficiencies, and tricks the player chooses to adopt.

For example, the Soldier benefits by having a significant number of combat-related feats (and feats in general).  The Soldier also benefits from receiving proficiencies which alleviate prerequisites for many of these feats.

From page 51:

> **Fight On**: At Levels 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, and 19, you gain 1
>   additional Basic, Melee, Ranged, or Unarmed Combat feat or 2
>   additional proficiencies.

(Compare this to the Lancer who gains one less feat over that progression and those choices can only be in 1 'martial' category [Melee Feats].)

Those are in addition to the 7 feats gained by all Careers (aka Classes) over that same progression.

This is enough, if the player chooses, to adopt feats that boost their damage potential by offering more attacks (*Charging Mastery*, *Two-Weapon Fighting*, etc.), or more damage (*Greatsword Basics*), or both (*Greatsword Mastery*).

Since proficiencies can be traded in for Advanced Tricks (such as *Fully Engaged*, allowing damage re-rolls in certain conditions), the proficiency gains are not merely fluff.  I've begun taking a couple for my character.

So, unlike(?) d20 there is no built-in martial prowess to these classes, but they can achieve them.  It does seem to keep the incredible damage dealing progression down.  HP (aka Vitality) does increase significantly with level.  OTOH, critical hits (which the Soldier is slightly better at dealing) goes directly to Wounds (basically, a character's constitution).

I've become a fan of the system, having only played AD&D 1e and a passing familiarity with Pathfinder.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the above reply, let me give a few other things to add to it.

There are standard and Special NPCs (aka mooks vs important). The former work off of a Damage Save instead of hit points or Vitality. They get a bonus to the roll where the DC is 10 + 1/2 damage taken so far. If they fail, they die or go unconscious depending on the type of damage.

There are several combat feats which allow you at the highest point of the feat chain to autokill standard NPCs if you successfully hit without rolling damage.

From page 87 of the Fantasycraft main book:
Cleave in Twain (Axe Attack Trick): If your target is a standard character with a lower Strength score than yours, he immediately fails his Damage save (damage isn’t rolled). You may use this trick once per round.

As noted above, Wounds are also there for PCs and Special NPCs. So when one suffers a Critical hit, it bypasses all the Vitality they have and goes directly there instead of doubling damage. So that PC Soldier/Fighter with 200+ Vitality/HP suffers a Crit then any damage from that attack by passes all of those points to go directly to his Wounds (which usually equal the CON score but there are Character options which can raise it).

Just to give you an idea of how potential broken certain combinations can be:

A 5th dedicated archer can have certain feats and be able to put 12 arrows into the air in a single round. Or a PC with the Great Sword and Cleave feat chains, along with certain character options can lay waste to over 70 goblins in a single round. Or the Skirmisher Expert Class which allows you at 10th level to designate an entire 100' square area as a Killzone which means any opponents of your party are considered to be Flanked at all times.